# How to echo all the_title() without text after last "-"

Tags: title

I am trying to do something but I have problem...

I wont show the list of my post, but from all titles I want remove text after last "-" (dash)

My list of posts:

> 1. My experience - this boy - first day - meet
> 2. My love - i do not know - second day
> 3. My first time - auuu - third time

I would like to return this:

> 1. My experience - this boy - first day
> 2. My love - i do not know
> 3. My first time

I tried this:

```
<?php $stringx = get_the_title();
echo preg_replace('/-[^-]*$/', '', $stringx); ?>
```

But this return whole text... with the dashes....

also I tried this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042170/get-the-characters-before-the-last-dash

Somone could help me how to output titles of post withoust text after last '-'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a PHP question not so much a WP question -- but:

```
echo substr($stringx,0,strrpos($stringx,'-'));
```

Also I think your example #3 is wrong unless there are some cases where you want to exclude more than simply after the final dash character.

Note - if you want to exclude both that final blank space along with the final dash that immediately follows it, then change the substr length by -1 to avoid the final blank space:

```
echo substr($stringx,0,strrpos($stringx,'-')-1);
```

Comment: okey, something has changed, but not what I wanted

My experience - this boy - first day - mee
My love - i do not know - second da
My first time - auuu - third tim

Just cuted the last letter...

Answer (score 1):

I fount where were problem...

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize

Each dash (short dash) is changing for long dash

I just wptexturize for titles by add to functions.php this code:

```
remove_filter('the_title', 'wptexturize');
```

and works well. But how can I get with long dash? I do not know... but I hope it will help someone in future.